# Correct syntax to inherit a models meta class?

Tags: python, django, django-models

What is the correct syntax to inherit a models meta class.

I have tried this:

Model:

```
class something(Base) 
   etc
   class Meta(*args, **kwargs):
        super(something).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ordering = ('created',)

class base(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        app_label = "someApp"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This particular situation is described in the [`Meta inheritance`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance) paragraph in docs.

Define an `abstract` model and inherit other model from it, `Meta` should inherit from abstract model's `Meta` class too:

```
from django.db import models

class Base(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        app_label = "someApp"

class Something(Base):
    # ...
    class Meta(Base.Meta):
        ordering = ('created',)
```

Comment: cool, I was not aware there was a different way for a Meta class.